# character input should be > = 8 character

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have a mysql Stored Procedures that need to validate password input that will input alphanumeric and will not accept less than 8 character. however, when i test it, it can accept even 1 character. im trying to improve the validation. hoping for some insight.

Thank you in advance:

Here is some part of the script:

```
  PREPARE STMT1 FROM " SELECT COUNT(column1) INTO @1 FROM table where column2 = ? ";
SET @a = x;
EXECUTE STMT1 USING @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT1;
START TRANSACTION;
IF @1 = 6 THEN
    PREPARE STMT1 FROM "DELETE FROM table WHERE column2 = ? ORDER BY seqid LIMIT 1";
    SET @a = x;
    EXECUTE STMT1 USING @a;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT1;
END IF;
PREPARE STMT FROM " UPDATE table2 SET column3 = sha1(BINARY ?),column4 = now() WHERE column2 = ? ";
SET @a = newpassword;
SET @b = x;
EXECUTE STMT USING @a,@b;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
PREPARE STMT1 FROM " INSERT INTO table2 (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,sha1(BINARY ?),now())";
SET @a = x;
SET @b = newpassword;
EXECUTE STMT1 USING @a,@b;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you've written already and what methods you've looked into

Comment: sorry , i have edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use `COUNT(col)` to determine the length of a password.

You want `CHARACTER_LENGTH(col)` instead.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

Comment: thanks,, i have change it to CHARACTER_LENGTH(col) but still something is missing on that part of the script.